# Panic Related to Garbage Collector When Running Go Program

Tags: go, garbage-collection

I installed a Go program from GitHub and when I run it, I get the error,

```
panic: Something in this program imports go4.org/unsafe/assume-no-moving-gc to declare that it assumes a non-moving garbage collector, but your version of go4.org/unsafe/assume-no-moving-gc hasn't been updated to assert that it's safe against the go1.18 runtime. If you want to risk it, run with environment variable ASSUME_NO_MOVING_GC_UNSAFE_RISK_IT_WITH=go1.18 set. Notably, if go1.18 adds a moving garbage collector, this program is unsafe to use.
```

It appears that there isn't much information related to this out there. I have zero experience coding in Go.

Any help is much appreciated. I'll be happy to provide any extra information you might need.

PS: The program I installed is metabignor and it was installed with `go install github.com/j3ssie/metabigor@latest`.

Answer (score 12):

you can also upgrade `assume-no-moving-gc` by using `go get -u go4.org/unsafe/assume-no-moving-gc` to solve this problem.

Answer (score 3):

the panic error is triggered by the library you imported.

https://github.com/go4org/unsafe-assume-no-moving-gc/blob/main/untested.go

```golang
func init() {
    dots := strings.SplitN(runtime.Version(), ".", 3)
    v := runtime.Version()
    if len(dots) >= 2 {
        v = dots[0] + "." + dots[1]
    }
    if os.Getenv(env) == v {
        return
    }
    panic("Something in this program imports go4.org/unsafe/assume-no-moving-gc to declare that it assumes a non-moving garbage collector, but your version of go4.org/unsafe/assume-no-moving-gc hasn't been updated to assert that it's safe against the " + v + " runtime. If you want to risk it, run with environment variable " + env + "=" + v + " set. Notably, if " + v + " adds a moving garbage collector, this program is unsafe to use.")
}
```

as what the error said, you need to set this env var

```
ASSUME_NO_MOVING_GC_UNSAFE_RISK_IT_WITH=go1.18
```

or, upgrade the go runtime to go1.19

Comment: Thanks. `ASSUME_NO_MOVING_GC_UNSAFE_RISK_IT_WITH=go1.18` sounds kinda scary, does it mean there's some risk of memory leakage? Is it safe to set? Go 1.19 seems to be yet to be released.

Comment: @edddd I tried to answer your concerns in my comment. https://stackoverflow.com/a/75465252/1121052

Answer (score 0):

A note for users that come from similar errors to this issue.

Your program may depend on the modules that want to play unsafe games with the garbage collector [go4.org/intern](https://github.com/go4org/intern/blob/192e9f60865cab39a69bb623e739cd2d57f68e49/intern.go#L98). If you update the toolchain without updating the library, your program may be exited because of memory corruption. So to prevent unusual behavior the program [panicked at startup](https://github.com/go4org/unsafe-assume-no-moving-gc/blob/ee73d164e760fd6e7da448468bc71793e75d7d41/untested.go#L25).

You can handle the panic in some ways:

- Open an issue on your dependency library
  (github.com/j3ssie/metabigor) repo [as others do with similar problems](https://github.com/grafana/loki/issues/8399).
- It's really safe to update the module yourself too (`go get -u go4.org/unsafe/assume-no-moving-gc`) when you can update the module.
- If you are sure what are you doing you can set the environment
  variable `ASSUME_NO_MOVING_GC_UNSAFE_RISK_IT_WITH=go1.VERSION` [when
  you are not able to update](https://github.com/grafana/loki/issues/8399) the module yourself. You can easily
  find the not tested VERSION from [this line](https://github.com/go4org/unsafe-assume-no-moving-gc/blob/main/untested.go#L5). Based on [this code](https://github.com/go4org/unsafe-assume-no-moving-gc/blob/ee73d164e760fd6e7da448468bc71793e75d7d41/untested.go#L22), I think it is fine to set the environment variable as a temporary solution but be careful to set the proper value.